# Перехват функций malloc() и free() из приложения через библиотеку

Tags: windows, memory

Подскажите, какие функции нужно перехватить, чтобы следить за выделением и освобождением памяти в приложении. Перехватываю через подгружаемую dll. Перехват malloc() и free() ничего не дал. Как перехватить память основной программы?

Answer (score 1):

Библиотека может пользоваться какими угодно способами выделения памяти. malloc и free дадут вам узкое подмножество библиотек, которые пользуются сишным способом выделения памяти. Вы автоматически пролетаете со всеми другими менеджерами памяти: у C++ они одни, у Delphi — другие, у .NET — третьи. Причём плюсы на всех уровнях поддерживают возможность переопределения метода выделения памяти (перегрузка new и delete, аллокаторы коллекций), то есть приложение может творить вообще что угодно и как угодно. Классы могут напрямую выделять виртуальную и глобальную память с помощью WinAPI. В языках со сборкой мусора всё тоже весело, и никаких malloc и free там вообще нет.

Зачем оно вам вообще? Чтобы следить за происходящим с памятью, воспользуйтесь профайлерами. Не надо изобретать велосипед.

Comment: Да, можно понаписать кучу велосипедов с различными способами выделения памяти, но даже они должны откуда-то ее запрашивать. Так что весь вопрос, насколько точно я смогу следить за памятью. Да, хочу смотреть за памятью. К сожалению таких профайлеров не знаю, подскажите.

Comment: @mikelsv Собственно, в соседнем ответе перечислили API. Но вопрос в том, что именно вы хотите отловить. Перехватив эти вызовы, вы получите выделения и освобождения блоков памяти, но конкретных выделяемых объектов вы не увидите, они будут запрятаны в потрохах конкретных менеджеров памяти. Вы бы сказали, чего вы хотите достичь.

Comment: Я и сказал про точность. Если в программе используется менеджер памяти точность будет меньше. Я хочу взглянуть на утечки памяти в программе без исходного кода. Сейчас наблюдаю вызов HeapAlloc() миллион раз в минуту. Очевидно менеджера памяти там нет и все работает через системные функции.

Answer (score 0):

LocalAlloc/LocalFree, GlobalAlloc/GlobalFree, HeapAlloc/HeapFree - вроде ничего не забыл... А уже всякие malloc и free могут дергать их.

Comment: Взял HeapAlloc и VirtualAlloc. Попробую и ваши. Да, malloc() дергает HeapAlloc(), Причем один HeapAlloc() дергает еще один HeapAlloc().

Comment: В dll может работать на других функция, там другой рантайм.

Comment: Попробовал на несокльких программах с перехватом пока только HeapAlloc и VirtualAlloc, вроде все работает и перехватывается. На той программе, для которой делаю, вообще миллион операций HeapAlloc() в минуту. Даже не верится, что это реально, но ошибок вроде нет.

Comment: @mikelsv вполне возможно что так оно и есть. И еще есть вероятность что другие API дергают эти функции управления памятью.